# Visual Studio Database issue with Adapter

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I try to run the program, I get this error and I cant solve it. Is it because I am trying to get the data from the same method.

```
rivate void populateTableTopping()
        {
            string query = "SELECT a.Name FROM Toppings a  " +
                "INNER JOIN Table b ON a.Id = b.ToppingsId " +
                "WHERE b.TypeId = @TypeId";


            using (Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, Connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeId", sizeTypeListBox.SelectedValue);

                DataTable tableToppingTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(tableToppingTable);

                tableToppingListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
                tableToppingListBox.ValueMember = "Id";
                tableToppingListBox.DataSource = tableToppingTable;
            }
        }
```

and get this error: in Adapter.fill
System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known managed provider native type.'

Comment: What error and what method?

Comment: I have the same code on @TypeId (TypeId use a list to connect to size list.) I want to do the same for toppings. So for example, choose the Size, shows you the type you can get. And want to add the toppings you get to add to that type. In windows form. Size 10, shows the type of pizza and then the toppings you can add to the pizza.

Comment: The Error is  for adapter.Fill(tableToppingTable); Exception user-unhandled

Comment: Also, it is using SQLite Database.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeTypeListBox.SelectedValue` is a `System.Data.DataRowView` and TypeId is **not**. They don't match.

Do you want the displayed text?

```
var text = sizeTypeListBox.GetItemText(sizeTypeListBox.SelectedItem); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeId", text);
```